# How do I use the Zoom in on Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I want to know how do i zoom in and keep it that way? I like to zoom in to 125 on Google Chrome. But each time i open a Tab it goes back to 100%. Is there any way to keep it from being 125 then going to 100?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Open the Settings, click on Show Advanced Settings and under Web Content, set the Page Zoom to your desired size.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from Google Support pages:

You can adjust the size of everything on the webpages you visit, including text, images, and videos.

> 1. Click the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar (the 3 horizontal lines on the right)
> 2. Select Settings.
> 3. Click Show advanced settings.
> 4. In the "Web Content" section, use the "Page zoom" drop-down menu to adjust the zoom.

That will apply the zoom setting to all web pages.

edit: LDC3 beat me to it.